# SQL remove duplicate rows that have same value in specific columns as another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to remove duplicate rows that have same value in specific columns as another row.

Input

```
Shape      Color    Size   Location
ball       blue     small   s
circle     green    small   n
triangle   yellow   large   w
triangle   red      medium  n
circle     purple   small   n
ball       orange   small   s
square     green    medium  e
```

Output

```
Shape      Color    Size    Location
ball       blue     small    s
circle     green    small    n
triangle   yellow   large    w
triangle   red      medium   n
square     green    medium   e
```

Basically i want to get rid of the extra row where the values of the 1,3,4 columns have the same value as another row

Can you do this with window functions?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: sql server, not looking for an exact solution, if i can just be pointed in the direction or if something like this is even possible

Comment: ok you can try my answer @UserX

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query. write a subquery and use `Row_Number` with *windows function*.

```
select * 
from (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Shape,Size ORDER BY Shape) rn
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE t1.rn =1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e669b/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you don't care about which Color is returned. This code uses a CTE to add a row number and then pull the first record of each unique Shape+Size+Location, and it takes the top Color record:

```
; WITH AllRecords
AS (
    SELECT
        Shape
        , Color
        , Size
        , Location
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Shape, Size, Location ORDER BY Color)
    FROM YourTable
    )
SELECT *
FROM AllRecords
WHERE AllRecords.RowNum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a group by clause.

```
select shape,size,color,location 
from t 
group by shape,size,color,location
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to delete the duplicate values from your table. Yes, a windows function is one of the more efficient ways to do this.

```
DECLARE @Input TABLE 
(
  Shape varchar(20),
  Color varchar(20),
  Size varchar(20),
  Location char(1)
);

INSERT INTO @Input
VALUES
('ball'       ,'blue'     ,'small'   ,'s'),
('circle'     ,'green'    ,'small'   ,'n'),
('triangle'   ,'yellow'   ,'large'   ,'w'),
('triangle'   ,'red'      ,'medium'  ,'n'),
('circle'     ,'purple'   ,'small'   ,'n'),
('ball'       ,'orange'   ,'small'   ,'s'),
('square'     ,'green'    ,'medium'  ,'e');


WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Shape, Size, Location ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS RowNum,
    Shape,
    Size,
    Location
  FROM @Input
)
DELETE 
FROM cte 
WHERE RowNum > 1;

SELECT
  *
FROM
  @Input;

--Output
+----------+--------+--------+----------+
|  Shape   | Color  |  Size  | Location |
+----------+--------+--------+----------+
| ball     | blue   | small  | s        |
| triangle | yellow | large  | w        |
| triangle | red    | medium | n        |
| circle   | purple | small  | n        |
| square   | green  | medium | e        |
+----------+--------+--------+----------+
```